# Truncate datetimes by second for all queries, but keep milliseconds stored in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, datetime

I'm trying to find a way to tell Postgres to truncate all datetime columns so that they are displayed and filtered by seconds (ignoring milliseconds).

I'm aware of the

```
date_trunc('second', my_date_field)
```

method, but do not want to do that for all datetime fields in every select and where clause that mentions them. Dates in the where clause need to also capture records with the granularity of seconds.

Ideally, I'd avoid stripping milliseconds from the data when it is stored. But then again, maybe this is the best way. I'd really like to avoid that data migration.

I can imagine Postgres having some kind of runtime configuration like this:

```
SET DATE_TRUNC 'seconds';
```

similar to how timezones are configured, but of course that doesn't work and I'm unable to find anything else in the docs. Do I need to write my own Postgres extension? Did someone already write this?